# how to search a name of text-file c# windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-files, local-database

I'm a newbie wp dev. I want to create a many text file name like 1.text 2.text 3.text ......1760.text and I want user to type the number in text box then click the button and the result is read that typed number.text. how can I do it ? please help

Comment: You can put all these files in a path of your solution.combine the filepath when user type the number like 'path/{0}.txt'.and then read it.

Comment: thx for your answer Chris Shao. I will try it.

Comment: sorry @ChrisShao but could you please explain more ?

Comment: Hi, @Kanamookob, please read my answer.

Comment: Do want to create them on the Phone, or as a build in content? What have you tried, and what problems you have you encountered?

Comment: Hi, @Romasz , I want to build them in content and the problems is I still don't know what I need to do because this is my first window phone app. Thank you.

Comment: @Kanamookob if you are starting with WP, I would suggest to read some tutorials, blogs and try some examples (http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-1-Series-Introduction , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680270%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx , http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/) On this site you (mostly) don't get answer how to write an App, but how to solve particular problem - http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method:
1. put these txt-files into a path,like:TxtFiles/1.txt,2.txt...
2. when user type the number and click button, execute a method to combine file-path and read the file. and you should check the number first.

```
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(string.Format("yourFilePath/{0}.txt",userTypedNumber), UriKind.Relative));
using (StreamReader reader =  new StreamReader(resourceInfo.Stream))
{
    yourContentControl.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
```